# Wrap parentheses

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to wrap parentheses around string in ruby, only if it isn't wrapped yet:

```
"my string (to_wrap)" => "my string (to_wrap)"
"my string to_wrap" => "my string (to_wrap)"
```

I've tried something like:

```
to_wrap = 'to_wrap'
regexp = Regexp.new "(?!\()#{to_wrap}(?!\))"
string.sub(regexp, "(#{to_wrap})")
```

but it does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. Your first negative lookaround is a lookahead, though. So it looks at the first character of `to_wrap`. Just make that a lookbehind:

```
"(?<!\()#{to_wrap}(?!\))"
```

And just to present you with an alternative option to escape parentheses (it's really a matter of taste which on to use, but I find it more easily readable):

```
"(?<![(])#{to_wrap}(?![)])"
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks. Also thanks for the [)] syntax. :)

Comment: @erik1001 in fact it's abusing character classes, by creating a single-character character class (and most meta-characters don't have to be escaped in character classes). I tend to use it for almost everything (especially `[.]`, `[*]` and stuff like that) except for square brackets themselves.

Comment: @m.buettner why did not you just escape parentheses? Is it better in some way?
`"(?<!\()#{to_wrap}(?!\))"`

Comment: @FUT `it's really a matter of taste which on to use, but I find it more easily readable` ;)

Comment: @FUT no. as I said, it's a matter of taste. I personally find `[(]` more readable than `\(` especially as there are unescaped parentheses right next to it.

Comment: Does it mean it's a bit slower using character class than escaped character? If it is, it matters only for very long regex, anyway I find it more readable too.

Comment: @erik1001 I would hope that the regex engine treats a single-character character class exactly the same as a single character. But I guess you'd have to do a proper profiling to ensure that for a specific engine.

Comment: @erik1001 No, it doesn't matter for very long RegExes. It matters if your RegExes are an identified performance problem and you get a boost by not using character classes.

Comment: @phant0m if the engine works by creating an FSM, then both versions should lead to exactly the same FSM. but in general I agree with you. no premature optimization unless it turns out to be the bottleneck.